# Benchmarking set up over HDD+SSD combination?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, linux, ssd, postgresql-12

I have a Linux system set up (Arch) on an HDD. I have been trying to benchmark some of my queries and found some disk IO bottleneck, and thus opted to move the entire PostgreSQL database from the HDD to my SSD.

I could notice a difference, however, I can't help but wonder if my set up is still imposing some limitations: I have my Linux OS, testing scripts and interface (psql) on an HDD, and my database server is on an SSD. Can I expect much better results if I move literally everything to SSD?

I am not so familiar with how the OS/DBMS interaction is working...

If it helps, the SSD is being exclusively used for the DBMS. And my data size fits comfortably over my RAM and SSD.

Comment: Why? What more info can I provide? And to be honest I am not expecting a very very specific answer. Sorry, I am new to this. Maybe if I can rephrase my question, I am just wondering if I am still incurring a bottleneck when my OS is on an HDD but my DBMS is on an SSD versus OS+DBMS on SSD.

Comment: Are your queries too slow for your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For database performance it doesn't matter much on what storage device the operating system or the software is installed. What matters is the database storage and the amount of RAM.

When fixing database performance problems, the first thing to try is to improve the query performance and resource usage.